# Checking String only letters and numbers except both

Tags: php, regex

```
"Hello" returns true
"12345" returns true
"Hello1" returns false
"123H" returns false
```

regex can possible check only letters and numbers except both?
or
Check function of PHP?

Comment: Your question is really incomprehensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=(?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Another variation.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/11

```
$re = "/^(?=(?:\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/m";
$str = "Hello\n12345\nHello1\n123H";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
/^[A-za-z]*|[0-9]*$/
```

Check for start of line, then any numbers of letter OR any number of numbers, then end of line.

A blank line will return true. If that's a problem change the `*` to a `+`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like so: `^([A-Za-z]+)|([0-9]+)$`. This will make sure that the string is either full of letters exclusively, or numbers exclusively, but not both.

You can check the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/wI8lV7/1).

Comment: IF start letter is "letter" it doesn't work well * "123H" returns false *

Comment: @GGu: Can you please expand your comment? I cannot understand what you mean.